# Compute $ \mathbb{E} [W(t_1)W(t_1 + t_2)W(t_1 + t_2 + t_3)] $ when $W$ is a Brownian motion

Tags: expectation, brownian-motion, independence

> Let $(W(t))_{t \geq 0}$ be standard Brownian motion, and let $t_1, t_2, t_3 \in \mathbb{R}_{> 0}$ with $t_1 < t_2 < t_3$ be arbitrary. Compute:
>   $$ \mathbb{E} [W(t_1) * W(t_1 + t_2) * W(t_1 + t_2 + t_3)] $$
>   using the properties of $W(t)$.

This question has been haunting me for days. I know you can write
$$ \mathbb{E} [W(t_1) * W(t_1 + t_2)] = \mathbb{E} [W(t_1) * ( W(t_1 + t_2) - W(t_1) + W(t_1) )] = \mathbb{E} [W(t_1) * ( W(t_1 + t_2) - W(t_1) )] + \mathbb{E} [W(t_1)^2] $$
("sneakily" using the independence of increments). Also,
$$\mathbb{E} [W(t_1) * ( W(t_1 + t_2) - W(t_1) )] = \mathbb{E} [(W(t_1) - W(0)) * ( W(t_1 + t_2) - W(t_1) )] = \mathbb{E} [(W(t_1 + 0) - W(0)] * \mathbb{E} [ W(t_1 + t_2) - W(t_1) ] = 0 $$
(where the first equality follows from the fact that $W(0) = 0$, the second from the fact that Brownian motion has independent increments, the third from the $N(0, s)$ distribution of any increment $W(t + s) - W(t)$ for all $t \geq 0, s > 0$).

So, $\mathbb{E} [W(t_1) * W(t_1 + t_2)] = \mathbb{E} [W(t_1)^2]$.

So far I have reduced the problem to
$$\mathbb{E} [W(t_1) * W(t_1 + t_2) * W(t_1 + t_2 + t_3)] = \mathbb{E} (W(t_1)^3)$$
but I don't know how to compute this last quantity, nor if this is the right approach, nor if it is even correct.

Am I missing something crucial?

Comment: Note that $-W$ is also a Brownian motion hence, for every $(r,s,t)$, $Y=(-W(r))(-W(s))(-W(t))$ is distributed as $X=W(r)W(s)W(t)$. Since $Y=-X$, this yields $E(-X)=E(X)$, that is, $E(X)=0$.

Comment: That's what I missed. It was a question asked in an old exam, and the exams of this course (Random Walks) are known to be quite easy, so I figured there was just some clever trick you have to use.